# Can this code be reduced using Java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type

I want to use Java 8 lambdas and streams to reduce the amount of code in the following method that produces an `Optional`. Is it possible to achieve?

*My code:*

```
protected Optional<String> getMediaName(Participant participant) {

  for (ParticipantDevice device : participant.getDevices()) {

      if (device.getMedia() != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(device.getMedia().getMediaType())) {

          String mediaType = device.getMedia().getMediaType().toUpperCase();
          Map<String, String> mediaToNameMap = config.getMediaMap();

          if (mediaMap.containsKey(mediaType)) {
              return Optional.of(mediaMap.get(mediaType));
          }
      }
  }
  return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your title to be more specific.

Comment: I don't like editing questions for other than cosmetic reasons.  However, your map is `mediaToNameMap` but you are using `mediaMap` in checking for the key.  I suggest you fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, since your Map of media types returned by `config.getMediaMap()` doesn't depend on a particular `device`, it makes sense to generate it before processing the collection of devices. I.e. regurless of the approach (*imperative or declarative*) do it outside a Loop, or before creating a Stream, to avoid generating the same Map multiple times.

And to implement this method with Streams, you need to use [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) operation, which expects a `Predicate`, to apply the conditional logic and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) perform a transformation of stream elements.

To get the first element that matches the conditions apply [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()), which produces an optional result, as a *terminal operation*.

```
protected Optional<String> getMediaName(Participant participant) {
    
    Map<String, String> mediaToNameMap = config.getMediaMap();
    
    return participant.getDevices().stream()
        .filter(device -> device.getMedia() != null
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(device.getMedia().getMediaType())
        )
        .map(device -> device.getMedia().getMediaType().toUpperCase())
        .filter(mediaToNameMap::containsKey)
        .map(mediaToNameMap::get)
        .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tested it out, this snippet is returning device.getMedia().getMediaType() instead of mediaToNameMap.getValue(device.getMedia().getMediaType())

---------------------------------------------
One clarification question : since we are returning Optional<String>, do we need the null checks?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Assuming the following class hierarchy (I used records here).

```
record Media(String getMediaType) {
}

record ParticipantDevice(Media getMedia) {
}

record Participant(List<ParticipantDevice> getDevices) {
}
```

It is pretty self explanatory. Unless you have an empty string as a key you don't need, imo, to check for it in your search. The main difference here is that once  the map entry is found, `Optional.map` is used to return the value instead of the key.

I also checked this out against your loop version and it works the same.

```
public static Optional<String> getMediaName(Participant participant) {
     Map<String, String> mediaToNameMap = config.getMediaMap();

     return participant.getDevices().stream()
                .map(ParticipantDevice::getMedia).filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(media -> media.getMediaType().toUpperCase())
                .filter(mediaType -> mediaToNameMap.containsKey(mediaType))
                .findFirst()
                .map(mediaToNameMap::get);
}
```